# The status "Required Reviews Completed”

Tags: peer-review

I submitted a paper twenty days ago, and now its status has changed to 'Required Reviews Completed.' I'm wondering if such a quick review turnaround indicates a high likelihood of my paper being rejected.

Comment: Stop worrying. Patiently wait for the decision and meanwhile focus on other work. The system doesn't give any information that would be a valid predictor of the decision.

Comment: Also relevant: [Can I predict the fate of my manuscript (from information other than a decision letter)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153925/7734)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all that update indicates is that the reviews were received. Don't read into it. Most reviews take a long time because people generally don't sit around reviewing all day. It might only be a few hours of work total, but you need to dedicate that time in an otherwise busy schedule.

So, 20 days from submission would be a fast turnaround (in my field), but not out of the realm of possibility. Most likely the editor lucked out and had quick responses from invited reviews, who then had the time to submit reviews quickly. There's no issue here (assuming you submitted to a reputable journal). You'll just have to wait and see what the reviews say and what the decision is. No reason to worry about it for now.

Comment: It is also possible that the editor wants to get another review. See here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37330/what-does-it-mean-when-an-editor-needs-additional-reviews-despite-a-status-of-r In any case all you can do is wait, and in most fields 20 days is not that long.

Comment: Of course, that wouldn't be unusual

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait. However, as editor and reviewer, I occasionally get reviews done that quickly. Sometimes as procrastination from writing my own stuff, or grading!